# Enthusiast or Fanatic badge using the Android app

Tags: discussion, badges

Just out of curiosity I was wondering, can a person log-in or visit TSE using the [Stack Exchange](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin) Android app and still it would count as a day visited for these badges?

Or does one have to explicitly visit the webpage only?

Comment: Yes. I have a 1000+ day streak, and use the app 90% of the time.

Comment: What is "TSE"??

Comment: @PeterMortensen Travel.SE aka the site Travel on SE network: https://travel.stackexchange.com/